# Mysql Timestamp field not converting into UTC

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I am using a timestamp column type in a table. When I store a timestamp value in it, it does not convert the time into UTC format. It stores the time as per the current time-zone. Following is the value it holds:

```
2015-06-17 12:44:27
```

I thought that MYSQL should automatically convert it into UTC. My timezone is UTC + 5:30 so it is showing time according to that timezone.

Does it also depend on the time_zone MYSQL variable ?

Comment: When you save a timestamp `2015-06-17 12:44:27` explicitly it will save the same value, and mysql does not do any conversion even if its timezone is set to something else.

Comment: Then should I store the date value instead of timestamp value ?

Comment: That depends on your application what you want to store, however if you want to store current time then you may use `now()` function and this will always store the value depending on the timezone set on mysql and if its set to UTC then it will store UTC value not your timezone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I should set the time_zone variable to UTC. So would it affect other date fields in mysql. I only want certain mysql column fields to use the time-zone settings.

I think only timestamp uses the timezone settings. Right ?

Comment: Yes once you change the timezone of mysql and when you add any timestamp value using `now()` function it will always take the time from the timezone setting of your mysql. If you are developing an application where users could be from different timezone a good idea is to store the datetime always in UTC and store each users timezone in users table. So while displaying something say a calendar for users activity you can retrieve users data where the dates are stored in UTC and then covert them to users' timezone by checking the timezone of user which you save in users table.

Comment: But the MYSQL documentation says something else. It says the timestamp is always converted to UTC from the current time zone. And the current time zone is the server's timezone that is configured in my.conf file. 

Thanks for the reply :)